# What's a DRY alternative to c++ header files?

Tags: c++, code-reuse, modules

In c++, is there any other way, besides header files, to use a function defined in file A.cpp, inside file B.cpp that would be considered good programming practice?

Comment: compiler extension that allows symbolic includes...

Comment: @gnat, that question did not list *alternatives* to header files.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/list-questions/info

Comment: It does not ask for a list of answers; it merely asks for "a(as in one) DRY alternative to c++ header files"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your restriction of "besides header files", the answer is: No.

The C++ compiler compiles each source file independently. If you intend to use a declaration that appears only once, it must appear in a header file.

(This does not consider things that wouldn't be considered good programming practice, such as including one `.cpp` file within another, or using `-D` compiler command line macros to define `extern` symbols in more than one source file.)

Answer (score 4):

[Lazy C++](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/) can automate the generation of `.h` and `.cpp` files from a common .cpp-like source, so you don't have to repeat yourself by maintaining the header file yourself.